# YouTube API TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: node.js, youtube-data-api

I have tried to get collection of search results like this with nodejs https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#usage

and there is function

```
function searchListByKeyword(auth, requestData) {
  var service = google.youtube('v3');
  var parameters = removeEmptyParameters(requestData['params']);
  parameters['auth'] = auth;
  service.search.list(parameters, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

the fucntion must return a collection of search results, but in my case it returns Request

```
$ node quickstart
Request {
  _events:
   { error: [Function: bound ],
     complete: [Function: bound ],
     pipe: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 3,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search',
  method: 'GET',
  paramsSerializer: [Function],
  headers:
   { 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
     'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/28.1.0 (gzip) google-api-nodejs-client/0.12.0',
     Authorization: 'Bearer ya29.GluVBXvsx3nP15QlV-MqcypX1eEvDQ3BuXttbfQyR7ZlTpfO26sZnrh7Sl0sWsOCdGsJWHpHtE9XJv0jDqoWmVOZoJbQLqqQs3ujIPlATDQBHxu5nNorO8JBCE6y',
     host: 'www.googleapis.com' },
  params: { maxResults: '25', part: 'snippet', q: 'surfing', type: 'qwe' },
  maxContentLength: 2147483648,
  validateStatus: [Function],
  uri:
   Url {
     protocol: 'https:',
     slashes: true,
```

and after all this throws an error

```
C:\Users\wwwba\Desktop\youtube\node_modules\google-auth-library\lib\auth\oauth2client.js:341
        callback(err, result, response);
        ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at OAuth2Client.postRequest (C:\Users\wwwba\Desktop\youtube\node_modules\google-auth-library\lib\auth\oauth2client.js:341:9)
    at postRequestCb (C:\Users\wwwba\Desktop\youtube\node_modules\google-auth-library\lib\auth\oauth2client.js:297:23)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\wwwba\Desktop\youtube\node_modules\google-auth-library\lib\transporters.js:113:17)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\wwwba\Desktop\youtube\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wwwba\Desktop\youtube\node_modules\request\request.js:1163:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wwwba\Desktop\youtube\node_modules\request\request.js:1085:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:15)
```

can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is simple than i think. 
i uninstall googleapis and google-auth-library and install their old versions

```
 "google-auth-library": "^0.12.0",
 "googleapis": "^21.3.0"
```

google, rewrite your api for new versions or warn that we MUST INSTALL OLD VERSIONS

Comment: Thank you worked for me! I guess people at google don't have time to update docs for average mortals like us :(

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution you found. :) Consider accepting it so others can see that the problem was solved.